# Correct format for routing by Id in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I am using the following route in AngularJS:

```
  .when("/content/:id", {
    templateUrl : "templates/content.html",
    controller : "content"
  })
```

and the following controller:

```
app.controller('menu', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('api address')
    .then(function(response) {
        scope.navi = response.data.body;
        $scope.selectCourse = function(course, index, path) {
            location.href=path
            $scope.content = response.data.body[index]
        };     
    });
});
```

The controller generates the templateURL in the following format:

```
#!content/2  //where '2' is a dynamic variable that changes with each menu item
```

Here is my question:

Is this the correct format for using a variable in the templateUrl?

```
"/content/:id"
```

Currently each menu item goes to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html#!/content/1
http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html#!/content/2
http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html#!/content/3
```

But the content isn't changing in the template as needed. BTW, everything works as needed in console.log, which is why Im thinking I have a simple formatting or syntax issue in the way Im formatting the link(s).

Comment: What is the expected output of the links `http://127.0.0.1:5500/content/1`??? And have you tried to remove the first slash of the url and just use `"content/:id"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `$location` service to navigate to a new view:

```
app.controller('menu', function($scope, $http, $location) {

    $scope.selectCourse = function(course, index) {
        ̶l̶o̶c̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶.̶h̶r̶e̶f̶=̶p̶a̶t̶h̶
        $scope.content = $scope.navi[index];
        var path = "/content/" + course.id;
        $location.path(path);
    };     

    $http.get('api address')
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.navi = response.data.body;
    });
});
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Using the $location Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

---

## UPDATE

> just need to figure out the best way to pass index to the content controller so it controls which element of the array is being called.

In the content controller, use the `$routeParams` service to get the parameters for the view:

```
app.controller('content', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    var contentId = $routeParams.id;
    var params = { contentId: contentId };
    var config = { params: params };
    $http.get('api address', config)
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.content = response.data;
    });
});
```

Keep in mind that when `ngRoute` router changes a view, it destroys the controller and scope for the old view and creates a new controller and new scope for the new view. Any data in the old scope will be lost unless it is saved to a service or passed as a parameter to the new view.

Comment: Its still working the same way; just need to figure out the best way to pass index to the content controller so it controls which element of the array is being called.

Comment: Keep in mind that when ngRoute router changes a view, it destroys the controller and scope for the old view and creates a new controller and new scope for the new view. Any data in the old scope will be lost unless it saved to a service or passed as a parameter to the new view. See update to answer.

Comment: The $routerParams addition to the content controller did the trick. As soon as I was able to pass the id into the element array of the response - viola! many thanks, friend. This was a great lesson.